# Passing arguments into SUDS client statement

Tags: python, soap, suds

I am using SUDS (Like SOAP) to test WSDL files. The methods contain types that are linked to further functions. I am not sure how to access the variables stored in the types that are displayed. Some sample code is below:

```
from suds.client import Client
client=Client('http://eample.wsdl')
print client
```

response is:

```
 Ports (1):
      (PTZ)
         Methods (4):
            AbsoluteMove(ns4:ReferenceToken ProfileToken, ns4:PTZVector Destination, ns4:PTZSpeed Speed, )
         Types (303):
            ns4:PTZSpeed
```

I am able to get access to these functions. I cannot find any documentation on how to test functions in SUDS. I want to test to see if functions work and checking their return values. Does anyone know how to do this?

I used the command below to display all child functions.

```
client.factory.create('AbsoluteMove.PTZSpeed.Speed.PanTilt')
```

I main problem is basically passing values into the functions and getting return values.

I have tried to pass the arguments but the parameters have attributes stored in the attributes. Below shows the layout for the structure of the parameters I'm trying to access.

```
(AbsoluteMove){
    ProfileToken = None
    Destination = 
      (PTZVector){
         PanTilt = 
            (Vector2D){
               _x = ""
               _y = ""
               _space = ""
            }
         Zoom = 
            (Vector1D){
               _x = ""
               _space = ""
            }
      }
   Speed = 
      (PTZSpeed){
         PanTilt = 
            (Vector2D){
               _x = ""
               _y = ""
               _space = ""
            }
         Zoom = 
            (Vector1D){
               _x = ""
               _space = ""
```

The parameters are more complex than just entering simple values.

Comment: I have the solution to this problem in my next post.

Comment: Can you please post a link to your "next post"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to invoke the method on the service:

```
from suds.client import Client
client=Client('http://eample.wsdl')
res = client.service.AbsoluteMove(profile_token, destination, speed)
print res
```

You'll need to determine what values to put in for those arguments to the AbsoluteMove method.

Answer (score 1):

`Client.factory.create` is for the instantiation of object types that are internal to the service you are utilizing.  If you're just doing a method call (which it seems you are), invoke it directly.